# Publish .NET CORE 5.0 API to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been struggling for these 2 days.
Does anyone know what's the problem? I tried to publish my .net core API to IIS, but always failed when browse the web.

I did the step to publish same as like this [webpage](https://codingsonata.medium.com/deploy-asp-net-core-web-api-on-iis-f75e755a6402).

After I browse on the server, `http://127.0.0.1:5100/swagger/index.html` , the page said No webpage was found. I am sure there no system/apps using the `5100` port.

Comment: Are you going to tell us what you did? or just a link to the article that works? *How* you published? How you got it to the web server? is there a website on the web server running? are you on the same box (or 127.0.0.1 won't work)...

Comment: Well, What I am doing is the same as like the link. On that Link, it's success to open the swagger. But I am not. Which part should I check?

Comment: at the end it says that your folder on the server should have published files, but I don't see where it describes how the files get there (frankly, I am not interested in reading that article in more details). Do you have files on the server in the first place?

Comment: @Felix, yes sure. I publish using File System, then I copied to wwwroot folder.

Comment: what is `wwwroot`? The article uses `C:\Websites\My Asp.Net Core` folder. If you don't describe what *you* did - you are very unlikely to get help...

Comment: Apologize, well I meant it's just a location. Wherever I put the publish file, should be OK isn't it?

Comment: I give up. You don't want to describe what you did; but expect the community to help you! It doesn't matter where you put the *publish* files; but it is crucial that you copy them to where the server expects them. Do you even have a working website? If you put a single file - `index.html` - do you get it in the browser? It feels like you are solving the wrong problem https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem

Comment: @Felix, got the answer from someone amazing. Check the answer below. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After I browse on the server, http://127.0.0.1:5100/swagger/index.html , the page said No webpage was found.

If you check the code of `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`, you can find the app will only serve the Swagger UI on `Development` environment.

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAppi v1"));
}
```

If you'd like to serve the Swagger UI on `Production` environment after you publish it on IIS, you can modify the code as below, then republish it to IIS.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "WebAppi v1"));

    //...
```

Besides, if your IIS site is just for testing purpose, to quickly resolve the issue and make your site show the Swagger UI as expected, you can try to add an environment variable as below for your site.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the first time I create web api using .net core. Really appreciated.